# Why is it showing error after windows update in vs code while Java programming

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

The program is lacking details, it is showing

I tried-

```
import java.lang.*;

class nir4{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("hi");
    }
}
```

But out> put came -

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\.vscode\.vscode>  & 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\eedc908950fb8b2a0402f354e7b375a7\redhat.java\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin' 'nir4'

Error: Could not find or load main class nir4    

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nir4[text]
(https://stackoverflow.com)
```

Comment: Have you checked Stack Overflow to see if there have previously been questions about failure to find or load main class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: How do you execute the code? You can look at [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) first.